# Podio to excel export received 400 response

Tags: podio

I'm trying to export xlsx file from Podio following the documentation [here](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/export-items-4235696).

But I received the following `HTTP 400` response

```
{
    "error_parameters": {},
    "error_detail": null,
    "error_propagate": false,
    "request": {
        "url": "http://api.podio.com/item/app/<fake_app_id>/export/xlsx",
        "query_string": "",
        "method": "POST"
    },
    "error_description": "Invalid value null (null): must be object",
    "error": "invalid_value"
}
```

The error description is not very helpful. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by passing an empty json `{}` in the post request body.